# Chi2 heat map for categorical data to test for MCAR: cannot unpack non-iterable rv_frozen object

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I want to understand if my missing data is MCAR or not.

I have a data set like this, where 0 means the data is present and 1 means the data is missing:

```
a  b  c  d  e
0  1  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
0  1  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
```

I want to understand if the data in column B is MCAR, so I want to make a heatmap of chi2 between all the columns (and if all p values >0.5, data can be possibly considered MCAR as far as I understand).

I wrote this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chi2

df = pd.read_csv('binary_to_check_for_missing_data.txt',header=0,sep='\t')
column_names = df.columns

resultant = pd.DataFrame(data=[(0 for i in range(len(df.columns))) for i in range(len(df.columns))],
                         columns=list(df.columns))
resultant.set_index(pd.Index(list(df.columns)), inplace = True)
for i in list(df.columns):
        for j in list(df.columns):
                if i != j:
                        chi2_val, p_val = chi2(np.array(df[i]).reshape(-1, 1), np.array(df[j]).reshape(-1, 1))
                        resultant.loc[i,j] = p_val
print(resultant)
```

I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "chi2_contingency.py", line 16, in <module>
    chi2_val, p_val = chi2(np.array(df[i]).reshape(-1, 1), np.array(df[j]).reshape(-1, 1))
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable rv_frozen object
```

I just don't really understand the error. I'm thinking maybe since the data is category, is it telling me I wasn't meant to turn the data into a np.array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `chi2` to `chisquare`.

[`scipy.stats.chi2`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2.html) is the SciPy implementation of the [chi-squared probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution).  Calling it does not perform the chi-squared *test*.

The function [`scipy.stats.chisquare`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html) performs the [chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test).  It returns the chi-squared statistic and p-value that you expect.